# Is AES statistically noise? Reliably so?

Tags: encryption, aes

Suppose we want to store files in a way that has plausible deniability. Ie. we can deny the existance of those files.

The approach is this: We allocate (or just use) a chuck of disk an initialize it with static noise. Then we write our file in there encrypted. We take care to handle the beginning of the ciphertext properly, so we are interested if an attacker can find out the place to look for this file, can they tell it is not in fact pure noise, but ciphertext?

My current implementation also includes a randomized hopping pattern around the chunk derived from the same encryption key. The purpose of this is not only to obfuscate the ciphertext more, but also to distribute the data evenly (all bytes are written 3-9 times) so that subsequent storage operations do not overwrite previous data so easily. I was wondering if one uses a more deterministic and public storage pattern, could a ciphertext be distinguished from noise if correct sequence is discovered?

Comment: ... Your first problem is going to be that the drive is going to have to mark that area used to keep from assigning it to other files.  At that point, it's obvious that **something** is there, so somebody interested enough can just resort to rubber-hose cryptography.  If you're using a custom file driver (in OS land), anybody who gets access to the drive more than once can tell it's different just by comparing bytes from the entire image, so hopping won't help you at all.

Comment: Your best bet would be a drive with a modified _firmware_ (eg, benevolent BadUSB), since that's lower than most tools are going to go, where the only difference would be that some file entries are exposed on "password" entry.  This would prevent imaging the hidden parts of the drive, or even revealing the true size of the drive.  Done right, this would defeat even some efforts of state-level actors.

Comment: AES is believed to be a PRP. When designing one should be careful, since currently, the [Veracyrpt Hidden Volume fails the plausible deniability](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81020/18298)

Comment: Clockwork Muse: In this case it is fine if the block is visible and known. User can save there just one text file called "testing.txt" and claim they never used it more than that. Hopping would in no case help in this, and you seem to not have read the whole question.   There is a problem regarding filesystem itself though, that I didnt specify I am aware of: Journaling systems would reveal how much of the blob has changed, even down to a byte. For this reason it will have to be divided into chunks that are re-encrypted separately on every access. This is doable if scheduled correctly.